# dynamic 4d array c++ with dynamic borders

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I try to make a 4D- array, seemed to work fine if the Dimensions WxXxYxZ are fixed like  W= 7; X=5, Y=10, Z= 2. But my code needs to work for Dimensions with varring borders:

```
int chainCount = 10;
int * beadCount = new int[N];// N >= chainCount 
// for example: beadCount = { 5, 7, 8, ... , 12}

//4D array:
double **** r = new double*** [chainCount];
 for(int i=0; i < chainCount; i++){
        r[i] = new double**[beadCount[i]];
        for(int j=0; j < beadCount[i]; j++){
            r[i][j] = new double *[chainCount];
            for(int k=0; k< chainCount;k++)
                r[i][j][k] = new double[beadCount[k]];
        }
 }
/*
...
*/
    for(int i=0; i < chainCount; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < beadCount[i]; j++){
            for(int k=0; k< chainCount;k++){
                delete[] r[i][j][k];
            }   
            delete[] r[i][j];
        }
        delete[] r[i];
    }
    delete[] r;
```

This always results in an segmentation fault. But only if I use  beadCount[i], by replacing beadCount[i] with a fixed number it seems to work.

Comment: Congrats you're a 4 star programmer now. I'd recommend you use a `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>>` instead of your raw array definition and let the standard library do the necessary memory management for you.

Comment: Even with the 4 star programming, please post a [mcve], not just code that allocates and deallocates.  Your description sounds like the problem is in the code you're not showing us.  Replacing a constant number with a variable number of items should not have caused any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest a better way to look at this?

Treat the object as a *container* whose key is a "4-tuple" `(w,x,y,z).`

If a particular "dimension" has a range-constraint, that's easy to implement.  If you need to iterate through the tuples, you can do that too.  But the container only *stores* the values that are actually set – all other tuple-keys return a default value such as `0` or maybe `null`.

There are lots of available container-classes that you can use here.  All you need is a function to translate the tuple into some kind of key that they can use.  `sprintf()` could do, for example.  The implementation of your class simply instantiates a "stock" container class and works with it while also concealing it from view.